# Duplicate instance declarations - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following type in `Haskell`:

```
data Cplx = Cplx Float Float deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Ord Cplx where 
    (<=) (Cplx x1 y1) (Cplx x2 y2) = compare(sqrt(abs(x1*x1) + abs(y1*y1)), sqrt(abs(x2*x2) + abs(y2*y2)))
```

Because Complex numbers are ordered not by its actual values, but rather by the abs values for r and i, I'm trying to define `<=` for the Cplx type. 
However, When i load my type Cplx in ghci, I get:

```
test.hs:1:44:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Ord Cplx -- Defined at test.hs:1:44
      instance Ord Cplx -- Defined at test.hs:3:10
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

After changing the Declaration to :

```
data Cplx = Cplx Float Float deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I now get:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
            with actual type ‘(Float, Float) -> Ordering’
Probable cause: ‘compare’ is applied to too few arguments
In the expression:
  compare
    (sqrt (abs (x1 * x1) + abs (y1 * y1)), 
     sqrt (abs (x2 * x2) + abs (y2 * y2)))
In an equation for ‘<=’:
    (<=) (Cplx x1 y1) (Cplx x2 y2)
      = compare
          (sqrt (abs (x1 * x1) + abs (y1 * y1)), 
           sqrt (abs (x2 * x2) + abs (y2 * y2)))
```

Comment: as a side note: there is no linear ordering on Complex numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Ordering) as you can se easily for the one you gave: (1,0) <= (0,1) and (0,1) <= (1,0) but of course they are not equal

Answer (score 6):

`data Cplx = ... deriving (..., Ord, ...)` causes an `Ord` instance to be automatically derived for `Cplx` which conflicts with the explicit instance you give later.  Change the `deriving` expression to just `deriving (Eq, Show)`.

EDIT: Your second problem is that this part:

```
compare(sqrt(abs(x1*x1) + abs(y1*y1)), sqrt(abs(x2*x2) + abs(y2*y2)))
```

is wrong.  You're passing a `(Float, Float)` pair to `compare` rather than two separate `Float` arguments.  Remove the comma and adjust the parentheses accordingly:

```
compare (sqrt (abs (x1*x1) + abs (y1*y1))) (sqrt (abs (x2*x2) + abs (y2*y2)))
```

Comment: I've added the question.